# Passing delegate object in the Where method

Tags: c#, delegates

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Where_MethodGroup
{
    public delegate List<int> WhereDelegate(List<int> list);
    class Program :IEnumerable
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            list.AddRange(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
            WhereDelegate lessThanFive;
            lessThanFive = GroupConversionMethod;
            IEnumerable<int> query = list.Where(lessThanFive);
            foreach (int i in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
        public static List<int> GroupConversionMethod(List<int> list1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Integers less than 5 are :");
            foreach (int i in list1)
            {
                if (i < 5)
                {
                    yield return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have to Find all the elements less than five by passing a delegate object in the where method. While defining the delegate object use Method Group Conversion Syntax for call back function to be used (Define delegate object through new operator).

I am getting error in the line:

```
IEnumerable<int> query = list.Where(lessThanFive)
```

that where method has some invalid arguments, what could be the reasonable fix for this error?

Comment: I am getting error in the line IEnumerable<int> query =list.Where(lessThanFive) that where method has some invalid arguments , what could be the reasonable fix for this error??

Comment: Where Method is an extension method defined in linq namespace that takes in Func type object. You cannot pas your own delegate type

Answer (score 1):

The `Where` statment get as parameter `Func<int,bool>` in this case.
You need to write function that get int and return `true` or `false`

Try something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        list.AddRange(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
        IEnumerable<int> query = list.Where(isInGroup);
        foreach (int i in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }

    public static bool isInGroup(int elem)
    {
        return elem < 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: List<int> list = new List<int>();
            list.AddRange(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
            WhereDelegate lessThanFive=new WhereDelegate(GroupConversionMethod);
            //lessThanFive = GroupConversionMethod;
            IEnumerable<int> query = list.Where(lessThanFive);
            foreach (int i in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }

Comment: but it's still giving me error that where has some invalid arguments

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            list.AddRange(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
            WhereDelegate lessThanFive=new WhereDelegate(GroupConversionMethod);
            
            IEnumerable<int> query = list.Where(lessThanFive);
            foreach (int i in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to make a delegate which takes as parameter a list and returns a list of integers, while you are sending in linq `Where` method elemets one by one (so only one integer) and you are expecting to return a `bool`.

If you change the signature of the delegate to be like this, it will work:

```
public delegate bool WhereDelegate(int element);
```

Then you can call it in the following way:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WhereDelegate del = (int element) => element < 5;
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        list.AddRange(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 });
        IEnumerable<int> query = list.Where(x => del(x));  
    }
```

using lambda operator `=>`

This is equivalent to writing a method and assigning it to the delegate:

```
public static bool Method(int i)
{
     return i < 5;
}
```

then at the delegate instantiate:

```
WhereDelegate del = Method;
```

And if you want to use the `new` keyword as you specified (even if it is not necessary in this case), you can write:

```
WhereDelegate del = new WhereDelegate((int element) => element < 5);
```

or

```
WhereDelegate del = new WhereDelegate(Method);
```

When creating the delegate.

Comment: but I have to do it using method group conversion syntax not lambda expression...can u plz modify it using this..

Comment: I have modified the delegate as u have said

Comment: Even if you define the delegte from a lambda expression, it is still a delegate, so this code does exactly what you are requested to do @Ananya

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
IEnumerable<int> query = list.Where(c => c < 5);

or

IEnumerable<int> query = from e in list
where e < 5
select e;
```

Comment: But I have to do it by passing a delegate object to where method ....the code u gave is using lambda expression...can I pass delegate object?